# Most reliable way to run Javascript in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, typescript

First I tried to run from a [`WebBrowser` Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

```
WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Visible = false;
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
webBrowser1.Document.Write("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");

HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
dynamic scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");

scriptEl.DomElement.text = "function test(fn) { try{ window[fn](); } catch(ex) { return 'abc     '.trim(); } }"
    + "function sayHello() { alert('ha'); throw 'error with spaces     '; }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);

var result = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test", new object[] { "sayHello" });
```

It works almost perfectly. It knows what a `window`, `alert` is... The only problem is that it apparently runs on ECMA3, so when I tested `"abc    ".trim()` it couldn't execute.

My second attempt was [Javascript .NET](https://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/).

```
using (JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext())
{

    // Setting external parameters for the context
    //context.SetParameter("console", new SystemConsole());
    context.SetParameter("message", "Hello World !           ");

    // Script
    string script = @"
        alert(message.trim());
    ";

    // Running the script
    context.Run(script);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't know what `alert`, `window`, `document`, `console`... is. Unless I tell it setting context parameters.

What else is there? May I should try some headless browsers and invoke using `Process`?

Comment: What are you trying to do or what are you trying to achieve in the end? Normally, Javascript is a client side language, and not executed on the server.

Comment: I just have to know if executing the function will throw an exception or not. My goal is to finish this http://i.imgur.com/ucJeuXe.jpg

Comment: I'm still confused at why Javascript is involved in this. Seems like your trying to create unit test on some Linq?

Comment: `TypeScript` is a language that compiles to Javascript. To run the test I need to run the compiled Javascript. That is why I need to execute Javascript.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `alert` server-side? Convert it into text output?

Comment: @minitech nothing. It should just not throw an exception, because it is valid javascript.

Comment: @BrunoLM: It’s valid in browsers. Are you trying to do headless browser testing, à la PhantomJS that Cameron mentioned?

Comment: @minitech I guess so. I am testing that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run JavaScript server side, I would recommend using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It allows you to run a full WebKit browser from the command line using JavaScript and command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is definitely not just for client-side scripting any more.  As Cameron said PhantomJS is excellent if you need the DOM.  If you don't, [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) is the clear choice with a wealth of libraries.

Comment: -1 for not answering the question, which was about running JavaScript from C#, not running JavaScript server-side.